# terra analogous of randomPoints?

Tags: raster, r, terra, dismo

I'm currently using the `dismo` function `randomPoints` to sample background points (bgp) over a raster. This function has an argument called `p`, which is used to avoid sampling bgp over cells that already have a presence point (avoiding pseudoreplication when modeling).

Since I'm trying to move to `terra`, I was wondering if `terra` has a function that could do something similar: sampling bgp over a raster and avoiding sampling cells that already have some presence points.

I was trying to use `spatSample` to obtain bgp values from the raster directly and then merge this bgp data with the data I already have on presences, but that — obviously — may give me some pseudoreplication (i.e., cells with bgp and presence). Is there any workaround?

Comment: You can check for duplicate observations by using `terra::extract` with the `cells=TRUE` argument which will return the cell index the point occurs in. You can then use ` duplicated` to find and remove duplicate samples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `predicts::backgroundSample`.

The goal for "predicts" is to be for "terra", what "dismo" is for "raster" (more or less).

Comment: I didn't know about ```predicts```. Will definitely give it a go. Thank you!